# Cant delete users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello im tryng to delete users, but this function dosnt work:

```
public function deleteUser()
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user ->delete();
    return redirect('empresa');
}
```

Error: Undefined variable: id

Comment: Where are you expecting `$id` to be set?

Comment: Where is that `$id` variable getting it's value mate?

Comment: Maybe you should pass in a value for `$id` like: `public function deleteUser($id) {...}` ...

Comment: please add more details in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps or answers your question. Try this;

```
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    User::find($id)->delete();

    return redirect('empresa');
}
```

Comment: @JuanSpada Yh, if it works, you should mark it as the answer, it helps others who will refer to this later

Answer (score 1):

Just to help you visualize what Nigel and Deepak are saying:

deleteUser() has to be accept an argument called $id

```
 deleteUser($id) { ... }
```

So when you call deleteUser() make sure to pass in your id (parameter) value:

```
 deleteUser(17);
```

Hopefully that helps you see what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to find your user to delete them:

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

Then you'll be able to call the delete method:

```
$user->delete();
```

You may wish to consider handling the possibility that this user might be null. There are a few ways to accomplish this:

1. Check if the user is null before calling `delete`
2. Using the `findOrFail` method when finding a user

Option 2 will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` which you can configure your application to handle this globally and return a 404 page or whatever you might want.

Option 1:

```
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    if (null !== $user) {
        $user->delete();
    }

    return redirect('empress');
}
```

Option 2:

```
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $user->delete();

    return redirect('empress');
}
```

Notice that on Option 2 we don't need a null check as an exception is thrown if the user is not found by using `findOrFail`.